# How to cin edges to each vertex?

Tags: c++, oop, vector, vertex

I am kinda new into object orinted programming. I am trying to input edges to each vertex but nothing seems to work out for me.

I want to write two numbers into console on 1 line. For example if n = 4 and m = 3, I can write into console something like:
1 1
2 4
3 4

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Vertices
{
public:
    int color;
    vector<Vertices*> neighbours;
};

int main()
{
    int m, n;

    cin >> m; // edges
    cin >> n; // vertices
    cout << endl;

    Vertices*  vertices = new Vertices[n];


    for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        // cin edges to each vertex
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using dynamic memory allocation (`Vertices*  vertices = new Vertices[n];`) instead of vectors? You should change it to `std::vector<Vertices> vertices(n);`

Comment: You should consider using sets or unordered sets. It will make it easier.

Comment: Tip: don't use plural names for singular things. You're going to confuse your future self otherwise.

Comment: What does `1 1` mean? Is it an edge from the first vertex to the first vertex? Are edges directed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read two numbers from `cin` first:

```
int src, dst;
cin >> src >> dst;
```

And then update the neighbours of the corresponding objects:

```
auto srcP = &vertices[src-1];
auto dstP = &vertices[dst-1];
srcP->neighbours.push_back(dstP);
if (src != dst) dstP->neighbours.push_back(srcP);
```